# Entity Framework dynamic linq where from generic source with dynamic where clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, generics, dynamic-linq

I am trying to query Entity Framework where clause statement with generic type when table name is not known.

I am trying to use dynamic linq:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> wherePost<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
            string predicate) where T : class
{    
    using (var context = new dbEntities())
    {
        string exp = predicate;//driverId>3
        var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var e = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { p }, null, exp);    
    }
}
```

This is the call example to wherePost

```
 db.Drivers.wherePost("City == \"Paris\"");
```

Not sure how to continue and query the `DbSet<T>` from Entity Framework using the `DynamicExpression`.

Comment: is the CLR entity type that is unknown?

Comment: it is known as we pass it =>this IEnumerable<T> source. .we need to query entity using linq to a table only known on runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you do not need to change TableName on the fly, but just query table via filter.

```cs
public static IQueryable<T> wherePost<T>(this IQueryable<T> source,
    string predicate) where T : class
{    
    string exp = predicate;//driverId>3
    var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var e = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { p }, null, exp);    
    var whereExpr = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), nameof(Queryable.Where), new[] { typeof(T) }, source.Expression, e);

    return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(whereExpr);
}
```

And usage:

```cs
db.Drivers.wherePost("City == \"Paris\"").ToList();
```

Comment: I am getting 'IEnumerable<T>' does not contain a definition for 'Expression' and no accessible extension method 'Expression' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<T>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: It should be `IQueryable`